# Finding records for indentured servants in South Carolina?

Tags: united-states, england, 18th-century, south-carolina, indentured-servant

We strongly suspect that our ancestor, Elizabeth Turley, who married Meredith Helm, came to South Carolina as an indentured servant.  She was born in Speldhurst, England in 1778, and was the only one of her family to come to America, having done so by age 15, when she was having children in South Carolina.  She lived in Camben District, Fairfield County, South Carolina.  Does a record still exist to show that this did happen?  Is there a history of this family?

Comment: Hi, Kathy -- welcome to G&FH.SE!  We encourage all new users to take the [tour] and look at the [help] to learn about how the site works.  If you'd like to add more information to your question, such as a list of what sources you've looked at already, you can use the edit link underneath your question.  While you're waiting for answers, try looking for other questions with the tag [South Carolina]((http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/south-carolina) to see if any of them can help, like this one http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/3149/1006

Comment: I am leaving your question open, even though it is a near-duplicate of the question linked in my comment, because your ancestor came from England and the person in the other question may have come from Scotland or Ireland.